# Question about basis and subbasis for stantard topology on the reals.

Tags: general-topology

Let $B_q(r)$ represent the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x_0$. Let $\mathbb{B}$ be the collection of ALL such balls, where $q$ is any rational number and $x_0$ is any real number. Prove that $\mathbb{B}$ is a subbasis for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it not true that this is actually a basis? We can take any open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $x\in U$, then there is an open interval $(a,b)$ s.t. $x\in (a,b)\subset U$ and for sure there is an open ball $B_{q_0}(x)$ where $q_0\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $B_{q_0}(x)\subset (a,b) $. So our collection is a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true. In fact, you only need to take balls centered at rationals -- the argument for that is just a little more difficult. This shows that the standard topology on reals is second-countable.

In fact, a more general fact is true: in any metric space, when you pick a dense subset (which might or might not be the entire space), then the set of all balls of rational radius (or even, say, rational radius smaller than some fixed but arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$) around points in this dense subset is a basis.

Comment: So maybe they mean a fixed rational radius r. Then if U is open and x in (a,b) in U we could have $\epsilon = \min\{\frac{b-x}{2},\frac{x-a}{2}\}$ then $B_r(x+\epsilon - r)\cap B_r(x-\epsilon + r)$ is an open interval containing $x$ in (a,b). So we have that intersections of B form a basis, and thus B is a subbasis. Would this be correct?

Comment: Does this seem right @tomasz

Comment: @H_B: Yes, I suppose that would work. However, it would *not* work in a general metric space. For example, it is certainly not true for $(0,1)$ with the standard metric.

Comment: Ah we have not gotten into metric spaces yet. But thanks for all the info.